# Not able to add multiple conditions in google_monitoring_alert_policy for GCP alerting policy using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Please let me know how to mention more than one conditions in GCP alerting policy via Terraform. I tried out several ways of creating a list of conditions as mentioned in documentation but nothing worked.

Below is the code snippet:

```
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy" {
  display_name = "Request count Policy"
  combiner     = "OR"
  conditions   = [
    display_name = "Request count condition"
    condition_threshold  {
      filter          = "metric.type=\"run.googleapis.com/request_count\" AND resource.type=\"cloud_run_revision\" AND metric.label.response_code_class=\"4xx\" AND resource.label.service_name=\"dev-ms\""
      duration        = "60s"
      comparison      = "COMPARISON_GT"
      threshold_value = 5
      trigger = {
        count = 1
      }
      aggregations  {
        alignment_period     = "60s"
        per_series_aligner   = "ALIGN_DELTA"
        cross_series_reducer = "REDUCE_SUM"
        group_by_fields      = ["metric.label.response_code_class", "resource.label.revision_name"]
      }
    },
    display_name = "Request latencies condition"
    condition_threshold {
      filter          = "metric.type=\"run.googleapis.com/request_count\" AND resource.type=\"cloud_run_revision\" AND metric.label.response_code_class=\"4xx\" AND resource.label.service_name=\"dev-ms\""
      duration        = "60s"
      comparison      = "COMPARISON_GT"
      threshold_value = 5
      trigger = {
        count = 1
      }
      aggregations  {
        alignment_period     = "60s"
        per_series_aligner   = "ALIGN_DELTA"
        cross_series_reducer = "REDUCE_SUM"
        group_by_fields      = ["metric.label.response_code_class", "resource.label.revision_name"]
      }
    }
]
  documentation {
    content = "The cloud run based request count alerting policy."
  }
  notification_channels = [
    google_monitoring_notification_channel.email0.id
  ]

  user_labels = {
    name = "offer-engine-alert-policy"
  }
}
```

Comment: Show the work you have done and the error messages and/or problem details.

Comment: Hi John, There seems to be a syntax issue which I am not able to resolve. I created a list of conditions but TF apply results in an error highlighting "Conditions block is not expected here* or *Missing key value  seperator* and *Use newline as block seperator*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The below syntax worked for me. Instead of declaring a list using [] , i repeated the conditions block and it worked!!

```
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy" {
  display_name = "Request count Policy"
  combiner     = "OR"
  conditions   {
    display_name = "Request count condition"
    condition_threshold  {
      filter          = "metric.type=\"run.googleapis.com/request_count\" AND resource.type=\"cloud_run_revision\" AND metric.label.response_code_class=\"4xx\" AND resource.label.service_name=\"dev-ms\""
      duration        = "60s"
      comparison      = "COMPARISON_GT"
      threshold_value = 5
      trigger {
        count = 1
      }
      aggregations  {
        alignment_period     = "60s"
        per_series_aligner   = "ALIGN_DELTA"
        cross_series_reducer = "REDUCE_SUM"
        group_by_fields      = ["metric.label.response_code_class", "resource.label.revision_name"]
      }
    }
  }
  conditions   {
    display_name = "Request latencies condition"
    condition_threshold {
      filter          = "metric.type=\"run.googleapis.com/request_count\" AND resource.type=\"cloud_run_revision\" AND metric.label.response_code_class=\"4xx\" AND resource.label.service_name=\"dev-ms\""
      duration        = "60s"
      comparison      = "COMPARISON_GT"
      threshold_value = 5
      trigger  {
        count = 1
      }
      aggregations  {
        alignment_period     = "60s"
        per_series_aligner   = "ALIGN_DELTA"
        cross_series_reducer = "REDUCE_SUM"
        group_by_fields      = ["metric.label.response_code_class", "resource.label.revision_name"]
      }
    }
}
  documentation {
    content = "The cloud run based request count alerting policy."
  }
  notification_channels = [
    google_monitoring_notification_channel.email0.id
  ]

  user_labels = {
    name = "alert-policy"
  }
}
```