# Adding multiple aggregations to a google_monitoring_alert_policy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, alert, monitoring, policy

I have created an alerting policy in the Google Monitoring Console with has multiple aggregations in the resulting JSON. Something like this:

```
        "aggregations": [
          {
            "alignmentPeriod": "300s",
            "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_MEAN"
          },
          {
            "alignmentPeriod": "300s",
            "crossSeriesReducer": "REDUCE_MEAN",
            "groupByFields": [
              "resource.label.project_id",
              "resource.label.database_id",
              "resource.label.region"
            ],
            "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_MEAN"
          }
        ],
```

Which is not necessarily supported by the google_monitoring_alert_polcy Terraform module. Which I have rendered as this:

```
      aggregations {
        alignment_period     = "300s"
        per_series_aligner   = "ALIGN_MEAN"
        cross_series_reducer = "REDUCE_MEAN"
        group_by_fields = [
          "resource.label.project_id",
          "resource.label.database_id",
          "resource.label.region"
        ]
      }
```

I'm not convinced based on my limited exposure to both Alerting configuration and Terraform translations that this does what I expect it to do.

yes, no, find another way?

Thanks in advance

John

Comment: hi, not sure if this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65359916/not-able-to-add-multiple-conditions-in-google-monitoring-alert-policy-for-gcp-al

Comment: Thanks @jspcal I'm not sure that they are synonymous. The display names changed between condition blocks, and I'm not sure that's an issue or not. I have two three versions of the alert and trying to figure out how to best test it. :( Thanks again!

Comment: applies hammer to his own head. I get what you're saying now. About to give it a whirl! :D

Comment: That did the trick, provided an updated answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

These work exactly the same was as adding multiple conditions. :D

This JSON

```
        "aggregations": [
          {
            "alignmentPeriod": "300s",
            "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_MEAN"
          },
          {
            "alignmentPeriod": "300s",
            "crossSeriesReducer": "REDUCE_MEAN",
            "groupByFields": [
              "resource.label.project_id",
              "resource.label.database_id",
              "resource.label.region"
            ],
            "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_MEAN"
          }
        ],
```

rendered as the following TF

```
    condition_threshold {
      aggregations {
        alignment_period   = "300s"
        per_series_aligner = "ALIGN_MEAN"
      }
      aggregations {
        alignment_period     = "300s"
        cross_series_reducer = "REDUCE_MEAN"
        group_by_fields = [
          "resource.label.project_id",
          "resource.label.database_id",
          "resource.label.region"
        ]
        per_series_aligner = "ALIGN_MEAN"
      }
...
    }
```

Rendered the correct output in the GCP Monitoring -> Alerting dashboard.

Thank you @jspcal for the nudge in the right direction.